# how to remove the tips?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem.

I made ​​a page with a form of the password change. but on first boot (before the user has entered data into the form) Prompts "is a mandatory field."

I need these prompts to be displayed only if the user submits a completed form incorrectly.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('drummersaransk',
    url(r'^$', 'views.page'),
    url(r'^userprofile/password_page/', 'views.password_page'),     
    url(r'^userprofile/password_page_changed/', 'views.password_page_changed'),     
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

views.py:

```
@login_required 
def password_page(request):     
    if request.method == 'POST':                                
        form = ChangePasswordForm(request.POST, request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = User.objects.get(username__exact=request.user.username)
            username.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
            username.save() 
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/userprofile/password_page_changed/')                      
    else:                       
        form = ChangePasswordForm(request.POST or None, request=request)

    t = loader.get_template('password_page.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
                                    'form': form,
    }, [custom_proc])   

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

password_page.html:

```
{% extends "page_base.html" %}

{% block title %}User profile - pass{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>pass page</h2>

    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.error }}
    {% endfor %}    

    <form action="/userprofile/password_page/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </form>
```

{% endblock %}

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.forms import ModelForm

from drummersaransk.models import UserProfile


class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password_old = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def __init__(self, post, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.post = post
        self.request = request
        super(ChangePasswordForm, self).__init__(post, request, *args, **kwargs)        

    def clean_password_old(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password_old = cleaned_data.get("password_old") 
        if not self.request.user.check_password(password_old):
            raise forms.ValidationError("old Password is not correct")
        else:
            return password_old

    def clean(self):    
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password1 = cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")   

        if password1 != password2:      
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must be same")
        else:                           
            return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be passing anything in the positional parameter to the form if it's not a POST.

```
form = ChangePasswordForm(request=request)
```

**Edit**

As I said, you have done some strange things in the definition of your ChangePasswordForm. You are accepting both `post` and `request` arguments - even though you're not actually using `post` at all - and, what's worse, you're passing them onto the superclass's `__init__` method, even though it is not expecting them.

The way to do this is to accept `request` only, but to do so in the kwargs. That way, you don't change the function signature, and you can choose whether or not to pass it onto the superclass.

```
class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(ChangePasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Exception Value: 
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post'
Exception Location: c:\Python33\django_projects\drummersaransk\drummersaransk\views.py in password_page, line 140

Comment: So it looks as though you have done something a bit strange in the definition of that form. You should post that code.